# custom css error class not applying for the fields jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form which contains two file input and two check box and one submit button. With my current code when the user click submit button the jquery validation will work perfectly but the problem was the custom error class was not applying and not removing correctly for example if the user click the check box that particular `errorClass`should be removed this was not happening. When i search through **SO** I  got one use full information it was mentioned instead of using border red for the check box or if the upload any file that particular field `errRed` class should remove and I try using outline-color but this was also not working. It might be simple somewhere I am missing some bit of code

I tried giving `$('.chk_requ').removeClass('errRed_chkb');` still no use

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/9Lrw5vz5/5/)

kindly please help me.

Thanks in Advnace

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vgza8p9w/1/

Comment: @Arun P Johny thanks for the effort not only checkbox the error class should work for input file

Comment: @Arun the problem this is working only for the i accept code not for the second one

Comment: @ArunPJohny any luck for the above question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remove class you can add empty div with `id="diverr"` there and give it desplay:none;

```
 $("#diverr").text("Please select Gender");
 $("#diverr").css("display","list-item");
```

if condition is false then

```
 $("#diverr").css("display","none");
```

Comment: thanks for the help but  i am looking for error class validation not for display none